# Creating drawables for density AND screen size?

Tags: android, user-interface, drawable, scaling

Is there a way to create drawables for screen density AND screen size? Currently I'm putting drawables only into the standard screen density categories (MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI). This works if comparing four devices with the same screen size but different densities. If I have another screen using these drawables, the graphics look either too big or too small proportional to the device size, which is especially noticeable on tablets. How can I make drawables to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence

Basically you need to avoid using "pixels" when setting dimensions and have multiple resolution images. Your images will be scaled automatically.

Comment: Yeah I understand how scaling works. It will create drawables of the same physical size for all devices; this is currently what I'm doing. But I really want larger screens to have correspondingly larger physical size drawables.

Comment: @mpellegr In that case this might be useful: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Yes, that would work if I wanted to just increase the size of a button or something. But it won't work for graphic images like icons.

Comment: What you want is called "scalable vector graphics" - images that scale without loosing quality. Android does not support it. You can give a try to this library http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense! So, how would I go about creating resources for all the combinations of: drawable-xxhdpi-small drawable-xhdpi-small drawable-hdpi-small drawable-mdpi-small drawable-xxhdpi-medium drawable-xhdpi-medium drawable-hdpi-medium drawable-mdpi-medium drawable-xxhdpi-large drawable-xhdpi-large drawable-hdpi-large drawable-mdpi-large drawable-xxhdpi-xlarge drawable-xhdpi-xlarge drawable-hdpi-xlarge drawable-mdpi-xlarge? I'm thinking it's only really reasonable to do all the densities for the average phone size an all the densities for the average tablet size.

Comment: @mpellegr I don't think that's convenient. Perhaps this from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html will help you: "Usually, you should use the size and orientation qualifiers to provide alternative layout resources and use the density qualifiers to provide alternative bitmap drawable resources."